# SSJS SFMC - Attributes.Retrieve(); returning empty values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

My code :

```
var subscriber = Subscriber.Init("myemail@gmail.com");
var attributes = subscriber.Attributes.Retrieve();
Write(Stringify(attributes));
```

It gives me the output of :

```
{"Name":"First Name","Value":""},
{"Name":"Last Name","Value":""}, 
{"Name":"Newsletter","Value":""},
{"Name":"Main Interest","Value":""},
{"Name":"Birthdate","Value":""},
{"Name":"Country__c","Value":""},
```

As you can see, the function works - it gives me Attributes. Okay, but names of attributes with empty values. Can someone explain why does it happen?
Subscriber key is valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm you are checking 'myemail@gmail.com' with Subscriber Key and NOT with Email address!
[image]

Actually I have faced the similar issue, where in the values were there in Tool [**which was my assumption!**]  but was NOT appearing in cloudpage!... and my mistake was I had the 2 records 
1) With **myemail@gmail.com** as my **Email Address** [I was seeing values of this record in MC Tool]
2) With **myemail@gmail.com** as my **Subscriber Key** [But, the cloudpage pulles from this record]

I did a quick check on this as even I received the same out put as you, but as there were NO VALUES!

#### In MC Tool

[image]

So I got the output as below,

#### Cloud page output

[image]

But when I added the values attributes,

#### In MC tool

[image]

Then values were pulled correctly as below,

#### Cloudpage output

[image]

Comment: Wow you're totally right! But it's weird. Why does my record has empty values?!

Comment: Hi @Richard98PL thanks for confirming it worked for you. It would be helpful if you up-vote my answer and mark as accepted..... and to answer your above question, there might be many possibilities. But as per my assumption these values are BLANK by default, and this SubscriberKey might be created when you SENT an email by using this record from a Data Extension... Where you have related EMAIL-ADDRESS field to the SUBSCRIBER_KEY!..as below https://pasteboard.co/INDrmBI.png

Comment: Hey I marked your comment but I can't give points yet thanks. :)

Comment: @Richard98PL welcome.... Hope you are clear, on your above query... when you send a Email from a DE, the attribute values will be BLANK..... they are most likely to be filled, when you import or bring-in LEADS/CONTACTS from other clouds.

Comment: I do want to note that there are many times when Subscriberkey should be email address - which is why it is set that way by default in SFMC. The major reason to not have it be email address is if you are ingesting data from an external system that already places a key on your customers or if have some other process that creates keys for your subscribers before they enter SFMC. Please either provide your rational for the giant bolded statement or please remove it as in the current context it is not correct and can be misleading.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, I completely agree on your point.. I have removed the bold statement, as it might mislead (y) agreed :)

Comment: @Gortonington - I find the use of email address as Subscriber/Contact Key should be avoided, for a number of reasons: It might not be available in omnichannel scenarios, where first point of contact might be SMS or an app. Also, allowing subscribers to change email address will leave you with different addresses across these fields - adding to confusion.

Comment: @LukasLunow - I do agree there are times when email should not be used as key, but a blanket statement in bold with no context in an answer is very misleading. Think of Subkey as a broth. Using Email as Subkey is like buying chicken stock and adding water, to make a quick and simple broth - where using a GUID is like going out and buying chicken bones, veggies and spices etc to boil over hours to make a broth. Although the homemade will taste better and is more customizable, it takes quite a bit more effort, money and planning. The stock soup still tastes good and is easy and cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in my instance:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try {
var subscriber = Subscriber.Init("xxxxx");
var attributes = subscriber.Attributes.Retrieve();
Write(Stringify(attributes));

  } catch (error) {
    Write(error);
}  

</script>
```

Are you using a valid Subscriber Key in `var subscriber = Subscriber.Init("myemail@gmail.com")`?

One thing you can check, is go to **Email Studio > Subscribers > All Subscribers** list and find the subscriber with Subscriber Key `myemail@gmail.com` and check the attributes visible available in there - maybe they're blank or a subscriber with this key doesn't exist. Otherwise the script should work.

Comment: There is no need to using try/catch since there is no error. I received an output as you can see, but with empty values. I have already checked those fields - they are not empty. Yeah my Subscriber Key is valid since, the method for retrieving subscriber works + if I would input invalid subscriber key I would have an empty array as a result. I have no idea why the script doesn't work. Any other ideas?
+ btw you should always write error.message, not just error :D that's tip from me

Comment: I just did some additional testing and run this script from parent and a couple of child BUs, gives correct results each time. And yes, if the subscriber key is invalid, it will return an empty array.